# Не линкуется boost на travis

Tags: c++, boost, travis

Собственно, не собирается проект на `travis-ci`. А именно, не линкуется `boost`.
Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
/home/travis/build/LordNeznay/StrangeWorld/libs/boost/lib/linux/libboost_system.a(error_code.o): In function `boost::system::(anonymous namespace)::generic_error_category::message(int) const':
error_code.cpp:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/travis/build/LordNeznay/StrangeWorld/libs/boost/lib/linux/libboost_system.a(error_code.o): unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

При этом, на локальной `ubuntu` все собирается. Компилятор gcc, пробовал 5 и 7 версии.

Сами файлы `boost`-а лежат в отдельной папке (`libboost_date_time.a`, `libboost_regex.a`, `libboost_system.a`). Буст подключаю примерно так:

```
set (Boost_COMPONENT_LIST date_time regex system)
set (_lib_path "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/linux")

find_package (Threads)
set (SW_LIBS_LIST ${SW_LIBS_LIST} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} "-lboost_system")

foreach (_component_name ${Boost_COMPONENT_LIST})
    add_library ("BOOST_${_component_name}" STATIC IMPORTED)
    set (SW_LINK_DIRS ${SW_LINK_DIRS} "${_lib_path}")

    set (SW_LIBS_LIST ${SW_LIBS_LIST} "BOOST_${_component_name}")

    file (GLOB _files "${_lib_path}/libboost_${_component_name}.a")
    set_property (TARGET "BOOST_${_component_name}" PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${_files})
endforeach ()

add_definitions      (${SW_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories  (${SW_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
link_directories     (${SW_LINK_DIRS}) 
add_executable       (StrangeWorldMain ${SW_SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(StrangeWorldMain ${SW_LIBS_LIST})
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы используете у себя и на сервере одни и те же сборки библиотеки, т.е. копируете `libboost_date_time.a` и остальные среди прочих файлов проекта.

Comment: Условно говоря да, так и есть. Таким образом я хочу иметь везде одну и ту же версию буста, собранную из одних и тех же исходников.

Comment: А так делать не получится. Потому что у вас наверняка система не точно такая же, как на сервере. Если хотите иметь одну и ту же версию буста, то придется прописать скачивание / сборку в конфигурацию трависа. Также, как и для всех остальных зависимостей. Если вам повезло, то может удастся что-то поставить из пакетов. Все это добро желательно добавлять в кэш, а то каждая сборка будет по многу часов.

Comment: А по какой причине так не получится? Вроде бы и там убунта, и у меня убунта - должно ж по логике сработать

Comment: Вот если бы там был Windows, и у вас был Windows, то тогда бы запросто сработало. А так, если используемые дистрибутивы хоть немного отличаются, то о всяком наивном переносе можно забыть.

Comment: а какой у travis'а gcc? случаем не ниже пятого? с виду эта ошибка связана с тем, что в gcc-4.7 при добавлении поддержки с++11 ABI STL'я поломали... с версии пять оно дефолтное... если версия `4.7≤x<5.0`, то должно помочь добавление `-std=c++11` в `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: @vtt, пересобрал буст под той же системой, все заработало. Оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ